# Dynamically add input filed into array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to add input field dynamically and ng-model must be in the below structure. I also want to delete items from array.

**Expected Json**

```
   {
       "Animals": {
            "animal": [ "dog","cat","lion"  ]
        }
   }
```

**View**

```
  <div ng-repeat="x in selected.Animals.animal">
     <button ng-hide="$first" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">remove</button>
     <input type="text" ng-model="x"/>
     <button ng-show="$last" ng-click="addNewChoice(x)">addnew</button>
 </div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.selected={};
$scope.selected.Animals= {};
$scope.selected.Animals.animal=[""];

$scope.addNewChoice = function (x) {
    $scope.selected.Animals.animal.push(x);
};

$scope.removeChoice = function (index) {
    $scope.selected.Animals.animal.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Here is the [workarea](http://jsbin.com/mufisiqeru/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to insert items to the above json like structure ?

Comment: Do you looking for something like this http://jsbin.com/jexujosuro/1/edit?html,js,console,output?

Comment: yaa thanks a lot. Is there any way to avoid the empty string inside the array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misused `$first` and `$last` with `ng-show` and `ng-hide`. Also, it is recommended the use `ng-if` if possible.

At first you should use `track by` for `ng-repeat` at least for performance reason. In your case, adding duplicate animal names will cause violation of key uniqueness of repeater.

I suggest the following code as a possible solution

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  this.x = "";

  this.selected={};
  this.selected.Animals= {};
  this.selected.Animals.animal =[];

    this.addNewChoice = function (x) {
        this.selected.Animals.animal.push(x);
      this.x= "";
    };

    this.removeChoice = function (index) {
        this.selected.Animals.animal.splice(index, 1);
    };
});
```

**View**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as ctrl">

  <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.x"/>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.addNewChoice(ctrl.x)" ng-disabled="!ctrl.x">addnew</button>

  <div ng-repeat="s in ctrl.selected.Animals.animal">
    <button ng-click="ctrl.removeChoice($index)">remove</button>
    <input type="text" ng-model="s" disabled/>
  </div>

  <pre>{{ctrl.selected | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

Here is the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wivobezuqi/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Thanks you so much :)